# Python keep generating same number

Tags: python, image, random, python-imaging-library

I want to 100 piece random generated image with 100x100 pixel.

But while i make this image i wanna change the color of the pixel's.

Somehow the images is always the same because its generate same numbers.

What should i change?

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random

source_img = Image.open("base.png").convert("RGBA")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(source_img)

Height = 100
Width = 100

R = 0
G = 0
B = 0

piece = 0
while (piece < 100):
    while (width > 0):
        while (height > -1):
            color = random.randint(1,3)
            if (color == 1):
                R = 255
                G = 0
                B = 0
            elif (color == 2):
                R = 0
                G = 255
                B = 0
            elif (color == 3):
                R = 0
                G = 0
                B = 255
            
            draw.rectangle(((heigth, 0), (heigth, width)), fill=(R, G, B))
            heigth -=1
        width -= 1
        heigth = 100
    piece +=1
    source_img.save("images/" + str(piece) + ".png", "PNG")
    
print("Images is done!")
```

Comment: You can simplify your logic quite a bit with `fill = random.choice((255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255))`. Or even define those as constants: `RED = (255, 0, 0)`, etc, and then `fill = random.choice((RED, GREEN, BLUE))`.

Comment: still create the same images :(

Comment: It's not particularly clear what your code is supposed to be doing, and how it differs from what you want. Can you provide an example input image, your expected output, and your current output?

Comment: so, i want 100 totally different images. The different between images is the color of the pixels. But its keep generating the same order of the pixels and make 100 same images.

Comment: @ddejohn can you test on your computer? maybe its easier to see whats it doing.

Comment: I've never worked with `PIL` before, but you do seem to be saving the original `source_img`, and not whatever `draw` is. What does `source_img.save()` do and how is it related to whatever drawing you're doing?

Comment: Seriously i dont know but its crate different images every time but the images is same. I dont know its understandable

Comment: @VinceMacKenzie, we won't be able to run the code anyway, because we will get an error that "base.png" does not exist

Comment: The base.png is a 100x100 black image. I created in paint just for get a file for overwrite

Comment: Looking at [this documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html), it seems as though you should really be using a context manager.

Answer (score 0):

You have some small bugs in your code. With an IDE and a linter, you can spot many of them, which can solve a part of your problems. The bugs:

- case mismatch in height-Height and width-Width
- spelling error: height-heigth
- height and width are not reset after an image is created

I tried this code and it seems good now:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random

piece = 0
while (piece < 100):
    with Image.open("base.png").convert("RGBA") as source_img:
        height = 100  # you could read this from the input image base.png
        width = 100  # you could read this too from the input image base.png
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(source_img)
        while (width > 0):
            while (height > -1):
                color = random.randint(1, 3)
                if (color == 1):
                    R = 255
                    G = 0
                    B = 0
                elif (color == 2):
                    R = 0
                    G = 255
                    B = 0
                elif (color == 3):
                    R = 0
                    G = 0
                    B = 255

                draw.rectangle(((height, 0), (height, width)), fill=(R, G, B))
                height -= 1
            width -= 1
            height = 100
        piece += 1  # this could be in a loop too, e.g. for p in range(100):
        source_img .save("images/" + str(piece) + ".png", "PNG")

print("Images is done!")
```

Instead of defining the variable you iterate over, in python, it is done most commonly like

```py
piece = 100
for p in range(piece):
    ...  # deduce or define width here or earlier
    for w in range(width):
        ...  # deduce or define height here or earlier
        for h in range(height):
            ... # do something with p, w and h
```

This PIL package is nice. Will check later.